# using interface to invoke 2 methods

Tags: interface, abstract

I  would like to declare an interface that who ever inherit from it
will automatically do 2 operation 
1-will write to log at function begin
2-will write to log at function end 
those actions will be done automatic 
the only thing the programmer should do is to implement the function decared on the interface
some have any idea on how should i implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with an interface however you can provide an implementation of an interface that wraps around another implementation and logs the function calls yourself. For example:

```
public interface IExample
{
    void DoSomething(string parameter1);
}

public class ExampleImpl : IExample
{
    private IExample actualImplementation;

    public ExampleImpl(IExample actualImplementation)
    {
        this.actualImplementation = actualImplementation;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string parameter1)
    {
        //Code to log function begin here

        this.actualImplementation.DoSomething(parameter1);

        //Code to log function end here
    }
}
```

Now suppose another programmer implements the interface as well, for examples sake, suppose their implementation is called AnotherProgrammersImplementation

```
IExample thisObjectLogsFunctionCalls = new ExampleImpl(new AnotherProgrammersImplementation());

thisObjectLogsFunctionCalls.DoSomething("test string");
```

Comment: hi there thanks for your quick response ,now  i need to inherit from ExampleImpl ? instansiate my new object and invoke the new method  DoSomething ?   i wanted to inherit  only from IExample i understand it can be done maybe by using an batract class  and an interface any idea?

Comment: No if you inherit from ExampleImpl you will override the logging functionality, you inherit from IExample and then wrap that with ExampleImpl as shown above.